# Printing multiple words in a line using printf() in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Im trying to print like below

```
2333 k4k3 34kk 34r4
233k 2344 234l llll
```

with command

```
printf "%04d \n" "1111" "1123" "3333" "3333"
```

but its breaks it. what I want to happen is all 4 values will be in single line and then add new line again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C style `printf` in `bash` expects each format specifier and an associated argument to be provided. For example

```
printf "Surname: %s Name: %s\n" "foo" "bar"
```

So you need to provide the specifiers for each of the arguments needed, something like

```
printf "%04d %04d %04d %04d\n" "1111" "1123" "3333" "3333"
```

(or) if you want to treat the entire set of words as a single string literal, you just need to use a single string format specifier. Notice below the quotes covering the entire set of arguments as one.

```
printf "%s \n" "1111 1123 3333 3333"
```

See [The printf command in bash](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) for more options and help articles.

Comment: works fine.  I guess it needs to set identifier for every argument.  thanks lnian